# How to get output using the following tables in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table - Charges

```
|opd_ipd_id|Serviceid|Amount|
------------------------------
|1234|1|145|
|1234|2|15|
|1234|3|0|
```

Table - Bill

```
|opd_ipd_id|BILLID|Amount|
-------------------------
|1234|981|145|
|1234|982|15|
|1234|983|0|
```

Output must be the following-

```
|Serviceid|Amount|
-------------------
|1|145|
|2|15|
|3|0|
```

Comment: Can you also share whatever have you tried so far ?

Comment: Are you asking how to query a table ?

Comment: Something is wrong. There are no ServiceIDs in your two tables with the value 1234 seen in the output.

Comment: @TimMonfries, Yes there is no service id maintained in BILL table so I am getting difficulties.

Comment: Well, you have kind of answered your own question, you could design the tables better so that Charges and Bill has a common and unique column which can be used as in the join condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT C.Serviceid AS Serviceid ,B.Amount AS Amount
FROM Charges C 
JOIN Bill B on C.opd_ipd_id=B.opd_ipd_id
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Serviceid AS Serviceid ,B.Amount AS Amount
FROM Charges C 
JOIN Bill B on C.opd_ipd_id=B.opd_ipd_id
```

Comment: You should try to include supportive arguments and explanations, you want people to up-vote your answer over others right. Rather than a code-only solution, the fact that OP has asked such a simple question highlights there is a knowledge gap, so take the opportunity to share the love and give back to our fine community.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller I just answered this question.

Comment: Yeah but that's not how SO works, per-se... this question has been flagged by the system as a low quality post, i voted to keep it, but wanted you to be aware that there is more you can do. For instance, why is your answer any better than the others?

Answer (score 0):

in both tables "opd_ipd_id" is the column!! you can create joins on..

```
select Distinct b.Serviceid,b.Amount 
from Charges a 
inner join bill b on b.opd_ipd_id=a.opd_ipd_id
```

you can remove Duplication by adding DISTINCT keyword ..

Comment: The result will come cross multiply like Cartesian product. ie for each serviceid align with each amount like service 1 will have 2 bills

Comment: #jito you have to use "DISTINCT" or "Group by" to solve this further..

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
SELECT Serviceid,MAX(c.Amount) FROM Charges as c JOIN Bill as b ON c.opd_ipd_id=b.opd_ipd_id GROUP BY Serviceid;
```

OR

```
SELECT DISTINCT Serviceid,c.Amount FROM Charges as c JOIN Bill as b ON c.opd_ipd_id=b.opd_ipd_id;
```